# wro4j maven plugin: how do I exclude files for jshint?

Tags: javascript, maven, jshint

I need to exclude libaries (like jquery, knockoutjs, jqueryMobile and some extentions...) for jsHint.

but for the other goals I need them all.

**EDIT:**

I've created 2 wro files but still it takes all targetGroups.

wro2.xml with utils,app
wro.xml with utils,libraries,app,jQueryMobile

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ex1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jshint</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!--jshint options-->
                <options>jquery,devel,evil,noarg,eqnull</options>
                <failNever>false</failNever>
                <targetGroups>utils,app</targetGroups>
                <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wro2.xml</wroFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ex2</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!--compile options-->
                <targetGroups>utils,libraries,app,jQueryMobile</targetGroups>
                <minimize>true</minimize>
                <destinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/wro/</destinationFolder>
                <cssDestinationFolder>${basedir}/target/webapp/css/</cssDestinationFolder>
                <jsDestinationFolder>${basedir}/target/webapp/js/</jsDestinationFolder>
                <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</contextFolder>
                <ignoreMissingResources>false</ignoreMissingResources>
                <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wro.xml</wroFile>
                <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.standalone.GoogleStandaloneManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Btw, a lot of configuration options you are using has the default values. That means that you can skip using them (since they are the same by default). I would recommend to use configuration options only when you want to override the default value.

Comment: I know, thanx :) that will be the next step. This way I could see the defaults and edit quickly if needed... thanx for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

1. Use separate groups for jshint processing only
2. Create a different model by providing the wroFile to be used for jshint goal only
3. Create a custom implementation of wroManagerFactory and exclude programmatically the files you don't want to be processed.

In either case, you'll have to declare the plugin twice in pom.xml, since the configuration options will differ.

**EDIT:**

The solution is related to maven execution configuration rather than to wro4j-maven-plugin.

So, instead of declaring the same plugin twice with different configurations, you declare it once with two executions and each execution has its own configuration. Example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>ex1</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <targetGroups>utils,libraries,app,jQueryMobile</targetGroups>
        </configuration>
      </execution>  
      <execution>
        <id>ex2</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jshint</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <options>jquery,devel,evil,noarg,eqnull</options>
          <failNever>false</failNever>
          <targetGroups>utils,app</targetGroups>
          <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wro2.xml</wroFile>
    </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: thanx, I've tried with different wroFiles and seperate plugins but no success. Creating a custom implementation of wroManagerFactory seems the only option but not really the best one.. (For starters, I don't know how to create a custom impl of wroManagerFactory)

Comment: What exactly is the problem when using two separate wroModel files?  We can continue the discussion on the mailing list.

Comment: Super! I'm pretty new to maven, beginners mistake :) Thanx a lot and by the way awesome work on wro4j. Consider me a fan!